# How can I export swimlane data in react Syncfusion?

Tags: reactjs, json, syncfusion

I have project that create swimlane with react Syncfusion but I don't know how to export that data to JSON file. I need to use this data with another developer. If I know this it gonna easy for me to edit and use less time to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use saveDiagram method to save the diagram as a JSON file and load the same using loadDiagram method. Please find the sample and code example below.

**Code example:**

```
let data;

document.getElementById('save').onclick = () => {

 // To save diagram

  data = diagramInstance.saveDiagram();

};

document.getElementById('load').onclick = () => {

 // To load diagram

  diagramInstance.loadDiagram(data);

};
```

**Sample**: Cupotx (forked) - StackBlitz

Please refer this documentation link for more details: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/diagram/serialization/

Regards,

Shyam G

Comment: Here is the sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tdjdeg-jrmfj7?file=index.js,index.css